# How do I send a String from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I've been developing an app where the User would log in into an Activity and there would be a Navigation Drawer containing "My Profile" "Home" and "Settings" fragments. In logging in, I am passing the "name" and "email" of the account retrieved from the database so I could display it in the "My Profile" fragment but I could not pass the NAME retrieved in the LOGIN Activity to the My Profile Fragment.

Code From Login Activity

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("first", extraName);
    ProfileFragment myProfile = new ProfileFragment();
    myProfile.setArguments(bundle);
```

Code from ProfileFragment

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            String name = bundle.getString("first");
            Log.i("PASSED: ","hello " + name);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_js_profile, container, false);
}
```

I always get the Error Null object reference

```
Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 31888

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.myapplication.JobSeeker.ProfileFragment.onCreateView(ProfileFragment.java:27)

    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Thank you, sorry for the bad English.

Comment: Log.i("PASSED: ","hello " + handle); what is handle here???

Comment: bundle seems to be empty,check it whether it has the string by using method hasExtra

Comment: @Jeeva, sorry that must be NAME

Comment: How do you add ProfileFragment?

Comment: @Bracadabra what do you mean add ProfileFragment? sorry. It's a fragment in one activity I just got it off a tutorial on youtube. now I can't seem to pass Data from Activity to Fragment

Comment: you can check if (getArguments() != null) then try to retrive and do this in on onActivityCreated() once to check.

Comment: is there any intermediate activity between login activity and profile fragment ?

Comment: @akshay_shahane yes, HomeActivity which is after Logging in, but the string is passed from LoginActivity to HomeActivity via Intent, what i want to do is to pass the string to ProfileFragment from HomeActivity

Comment: are you passing data from home activity to profileFragment ? if no getArguments will always be null

Comment: @akshay_shahane yes, just by the Code from LoginActivity I posted above. Is there something lacking?

Comment: @A S, I mean how do you add your fragment to FragmentManager or do you declare it in xml?

Answer (score 0):

Mention, your fragment is in the same activity or in different activity.
According to your question, your fragment code is inside the wrong *method* or *function* you are trying to print or getting string even `view` is not created.

`override onActivityCreated()` method inside your fragment and put these lines of code in it.

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
            String name = bundle.getString("first");
            Log.i("PASSED: ","hello " + name);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

And do not disturb anything inside your `onCreateView()` method just cut above these line of code and paste into `onActivityCreated()`

Comment: My fragment is in HomeActivity accessed after loggin in on LoginActivity. The Data is in Home Activity which are where the Fragments are, but I can't access it from the Java class "ProfileFragment.java"

Comment: So you are saying techinicaly you have two activties.. one for login and other activity which has fragment. right? And kindly let me know, did you try above mention solution

Comment: Yes I tried it, it still did not work :( thank you though. I just created this Navigation Drawer with fragments with the help of youtube but did not exactly understand how it was working

Comment: Ok now struggle little bit more, **Update** your question and add your all XML's code, your all fragments and activities full code with the classes name. Then your point will be understandable more.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_js_profile, container, false);
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            String name = bundle.getString("first");
            Log.i("PASSED: ","hello " + name);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Hello " + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        return view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers, my error was in the Switch Case code

```
            case R.id.nav_profile:
            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", name);
            profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ProfileFragment())
                    .commit();
            break;
```

Sorry for not posting this earlier, I was sending data on my onCreate method, and i put NEW ProfileFragment() which kept on creating a new Fragment and it shouldve been like this

```
            case R.id.nav_profile:
            String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("name", name);
            profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, profileFragment)
                    .commit();
            break;
```

All of your answers helped! thank you :)